# How to implement a streaks feature

Tags: java, android

I wish to implement a sort of streaks feature showing a count of the number of times the user opens the app. I would like the counter to increase by one per day. If the user should skip a day, save the counter as a sort of "high score" and restart the counter

So far I have been able to count the number of times the app is opened using the code below:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //initialize streak counter
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        streakCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
        streakCount++;
        editor.putInt("counter", streakCount);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(this, "App Opened Count is: " + streakCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Any ideas on how to implement this will be appreciated.

Comment: strekcount is string?

Comment: you need to add day and time library to check if user skip a day then you restart the counter

Comment: @WaleedAsim it is an int

Comment: @WaleedAsim I am very new to java and android programming. Is it possible to refer me to some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just use this as a sample**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int thisDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); // GET THE CURRENT DAY OF THE YEAR

        int lastDay = sharedPreferences.getInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", 0); //If we don't have a saved value, use 0.

        int counterOfConsecutiveDays = sharedPreferences.getInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", 0); //If we don't have a saved value, use 0.

if(lastDay == thisDay -1){
    // CONSECUTIVE DAYS
    counterOfConsecutiveDays = counterOfConsecutiveDays + 1;

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", thisDay);

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", counterOfConsecutiveDays).commit;
} else {

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", thisDay);

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", 1).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WaleedAsim I will give this a go and get back to you.

Comment: @EricW if it solve your problem then click tick for mark as solution

Comment: I want you to know that you're a life saver. I just asked a similar question and found yours just now. Thank you.

Comment: its works fine but sometime streak come back to 1

Comment: what if user change their time in mobile ?